# How to import core elements and paper elements in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, polymer, jsfiddle, paper-elements, core-elements

How can I import [core elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html) and [paper elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html) in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

I'm importing [polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) through those statements:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.4.2/platform.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.4.2/polymer.js"></script>
```

How can import for example [`core-input`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-input) or [`paper-input`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-input)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes from the polymer project site or I guess your cloudflare cdn if you know the location

```
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
```

This is just for dev and not production.

If you goto [polymer elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/) then choose your element and click on the button that says Get Element it will give you a popup with an import link.

Also you can get a link for all core or paper elements from [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/usingelements.html)

Comment: It seems these no longer work since 1.0. They give `404`. But you can grab them from [polymer-cdn](https://github.com/download/polymer-cdn).

Comment: Ah I figured it out. For the old version these can still be used, but you have to add `0.5` to the url: http://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/polymer/polymer.html

Comment: I think it is very scary though that (apart from the `0.5`) there is no version in the URL. I personally think you should always use URLs to a specific version, not to some 'master' that can change at any moment...

Answer (score 4):

A good alternative  - still a work in progress - is https://ele.io/

Ele (call it “Ellie”) is a streamlined environment for exploring, experimenting with, and sharing reusable custom HTML elements made with Web Components.

Comment: That looks really outdated. GitHub repo last updated December 2014, and there seems to be no support for Polymer 1.0. https://github.com/divshot/ele-web

Comment: One of the creators of Ele here -- would love to update it for Polymer 1.0, just haven't had the time.

Answer (score 0):

To test a simple component written in Polymer 1.0 I use this snippet:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Polymer/polymer/master/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="proto-element">
    <template>
        <span>I'm <b>proto-element</b>. Check out my prototype.</span>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "proto-element",
        ready: function() {
            //...
        }
    });
</script>

<proto-element></proto-element>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MartyIX/84b5sabw/